# React query doesn't sustain its cache after queryClient.setQueryData

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

React query doesn't sustain its cache after queryClient.setQueryData, also it's not working on defaultOptions like under.
i am using react query developer tool and it show that that data get stored after API call but i saw a property gcTimeout: 23. i think this is effecting and have tried every possible solution available on internet.

```
// defined in app.tsx


const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
      cacheTime: 100000, // 10 min
    },
  },
});


<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
```

let me share the custom hook i created for mutation.
and how i am calling it.

```
// defined in hooks/useFetch.ts


const useFetch = (requests: Request[]) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const fetchDataAndMutate = () => {
    return requests.map((request) => {
      const {
        key,
        api, 
        save = true,
      } = request;

      
      const {mutate, isLoading} = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async (payload) => postUtil(api, payload),
        onMutate: (variables) => {
          return {id: 1};
        },
        onError: (error, variables, context) => {
          // An error happened!
          console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
        },
        onSuccess: (response, variables, context) => {
          if (response.status) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              //success
              if (save) queryClient.setQueryData([key], response.data.data);
            }
          } else if (response.response.status) {
            console.log(
              "response.response.status",
              response.response.data.Message
            );
          }
        },
      });
      return {
        mutate,
        isLoading,
      };
    });
  };
  const mutates = fetchDataAndMutate();

  useEffect(() => {
    // to hit api as it is defined
    requests.forEach((request, index) => {
      if (request?.init)
        if (typeof mutates[index].mutate === "function")
          mutates[index].mutate();
    });
  }, []);

  return mutates;
};
```

used the hooks as following ->

```
// defined in containers/analysis

const apiConfig = [
  {
    key: ALL_MAPPING_AREAS,
    api: getAllMappingAreasApi, 
    init: true,
  },
  {
    key: MAPPING_AREA_DETAIL,
    api: getMappingAreaDetailApi, 
  },
];

const mutates = useFetch(apiConfig);
const [
  getAllMappingAreas,
  getBoundedAreaDetail,
] = mutates;


const allMappingAreas = queryClient.getQueryData([ALL_MAPPING_AREAS]);
const mappingAreaDetail = queryClient.getQueryData([MAPPING_AREA_DETAIL]);

// i am receiving data in allMappingAreas but it vanish fater almost 5min
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating an Observer because you are not using the `useQuery` hook, so the Query counts as "unused" and is garbage collected after the default of 5 minutes.

You can just tweak `cacheTime` to be a different value, however, it's not a good idea to retrieve data with `queryClient.getQueryData` - you *really* want to use `useQuery` to get a reactive hook that will automatically re-render your component when updates come in for that Query. Using mutations instead (for GET requests in general) is not a good idea because mutations don't share or deduplicate state like queries do.

Comment: i really appreciate the time you get to answer. the reason for not using useQuery was that I had to use POST method and I am getting data through POST api after passing it some payload.  i cannot change api as it is being designed and fnalized so i need to manage it on client side.

Comment: now i have changed it exactly where the problem is. it would be easy to understand.

Comment: what about the use case where queryData is needed by functions outside of components?